# How can I create this optional WHERE clause for user filtering in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

On my frontend, I have a multiselect that allows the user to filter clients. However, The user may only want to filter with "country" and "bonus_points"... leaving the other filters unused.

I have two tables that contain userdata... users, and users_ext. How can I create a query that conditionally checks these WHERE clauses?

Also, as a bonus, how would I then allow an optional EXCLUSION filter? Is it possible to do this all in one query?

```
SELECT uuid
    FROM users
    JOIN users_ext ON users.uuid = users_ext.uuid
    WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR users_ext.country IN (ARRAY[$1])) AND
    WHERE ($2 IS NULL OR users.birthday IN (ARRAY[$2])) AND
    WHERE ($3 IS NULL OR users_ext.account_age IN (ARRAY[$3])) AND
    WHERE ($4 IS NULL OR users_ext.bonus_points IN (ARRAY[$4]))
```

Comment: simply fill $2 or $3 with NULL

Answer (score 0):

Start with a piece of SQL that is valid, something like this:

```
SELECT uuid
    FROM users
    JOIN users_ext ON users.uuid = users_ext.uuid
WHERE TRUE
```

And when you have some filters, add the extra conditions:

```
AND ($1 IS NULL OR users_ext.country =ANY (ARRAY[$1]))
```

And another condition:

```
AND ($2 IS NULL OR users.birthday =ANY (ARRAY[$2]))
```

All together you get something like this:

```
SELECT uuid
    FROM users
    JOIN users_ext ON users.uuid = users_ext.uuid
WHERE TRUE -- to get a correct WHERE in your statement
AND ($1 IS NULL OR users_ext.country =ANY (ARRAY[$1]))
AND ($2 IS NULL OR users.birthday =ANY (ARRAY[$2]))
```

But as you know, you can only have a single WHERE in your (sub) query

Comment: I am getting an error about unable to compare text to text[]. I am trying to fix this using the ANY keyword as follows:  ($1 IS NULL OR users_ext.country IN (ANY ARRAY[$1])), but am getting syntax error near or at "ANY"

Comment: @cantfetzthis Sorry, missed that error, you need =ANY()